# Calling functions without closing the master window - Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I've tried to create a software. In this software there is a menu widget with function button that open functions e widgets. But, I've noticed, to keep going on script, it's necessary to  close the master window (menu).
I've created an example to you understand my problem.

```
from tkinter import *

#Create Fuction that open new fuctions and widget
def test():
    #Open a new widget
    def fun_test_1():
        top_level = Tk()
        def test1():
            top_level1 = Toplevel()
            top_level1.title('new1')
            top_level1.mainloop()
        Button(top_level, text='test1',command=test1).pack()
        top_level.mainloop()
    fun_test_1()

    #Before, open the second widget
    def fun_test_2():
        print('def fun_test_2(): works!')
        top_level = Tk()
        def test1():
            top_level1 = Toplevel()
            top_level1.title('new1')
            top_level1.mainloop()

        Button(top_level, text='Button', command=test1).pack()
        top_level.mainloop()
    fun_test_2()

root = Tk()
root.title('MASTER')
Button(root, text='Button',command=test).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So, I need that fun_test_2() be called without close the root widget

And all functions i've tried to change Tk() to Toplevel() and Toplevel() to Tk().

Comment: Why do you think you need to close the window before calling `fun_test_2()`? Also, why are you creating multiple instances of `Tk`? Unless you understand why, you should not create more than one instance of `Tk` or call `mainloop` more than once in an application.

Comment: @bryan-oakley - I don't think. Is like I told. If U run the code will see too. What I created is an example that gives the same error in my software.
I need to terminate fun_test_1() function and call fun_test_2() without closing root

Comment: Why are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: To open new widgets. In this code, it's just an example of my problem. It is not the complete code. I need to finish the fun_test_1 and start fn_test_2, without close the root widget.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you calling `mainloop` more than once, and for creating more than one instance of `Tk`. When you call `mainloop`, it won't return until that window has been destroyed. That's a fundamental aspect of how tkinter works.

The solution is to not create more than one instance of `Tk` and to not call `mainloop` more than once. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`. And again, only call `mainloop` once in total, not once per window.

Comment: Thanks! I could understand! But, what I can do? Theres a way to do this? The Master widget don't can be destroyed and I need to open new fuctions one by one.

Comment: @ViniciusNogueira: I don’t know what you mean. You can call as many functions and open as many windows as you want. If you need a new window, create a `Toplevel`

Comment: Is there a way that I can send U a video?